# Why is my login method declared as static?

Tags: java

Here while i was debugging i found out that login method is a static method?.

1. Does it give more security to the
   method?
2. Generally what type of method
   should be made static? and how do i
   decide on that?

   static public Account logIn(String email, String password) {

Comment: What exactly makes that code a "service"? Is there a specific reason you don't call it by the more common name "method"?

Comment: This method is used in many application, i prefer it to be called as a service than method... anyway changed back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant see any security benefits in making a method static.

Ideally services should be exposed via interfaces so that different implementations can easily be swapped in; this also supports unit testing. Methods declared as static are generally helper methods that dont require state.

Perhaps in your case, this service was exposed as static so that it can be easily referenced throughout the code base, without having to look-up (or wire in) the service instance.

Answer (score 1):

Being `static` does not influence "security" in any significant way.

In fact, "security" can mean a ton of different things in this context (none of which I see influenced by the static-ness of the method).

A method *can* be made static when it doesn't need to access any non-static members of its class. A method *should* be made static when its operation should be independent from any specific object of its class.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question can be found in any basic object oriented programming book. The basic OO concepts are ideal for use in Java, as java is an OO language.

In general authentication will need to collaborate with other object in order to achieve something... It will need access to a user store, possibly access to an encryption or hashing service.

If your method has no state, and uses only the objects passes in, and returns all outputs as the output of the method, then it may be a good candidate for making static, but this has no effect at all on security.